# Aggregate very big numbers by reading a file in perl

Tags: perl

There is a file which contains more than 20 million records. I need to use perl to aggregate the numbers and print the TOTAL on the last line. The numbers that I am supposed to aggregate are very big numbers and they could be positive or negative. I am using bignum module of perl to aggregate the numbers. However, it is not showing the correct results. Please advise.

sample.txt (in reality, this file contains more than 20 million records):

```
12345678910111213.00
14151617181920212.12345
23242526272829301.54321
32333435363738394.23456
-41424344454647489.65432
```

Expected output (my perl one liner is showing incorrect TOTAL on the last line):

```
12345678910111213.00
14151617181920212.12345
23242526272829301.54321
32333435363738394.23456
-41424344454647489.65432
TOTAL=<<total_should_be_printed>>
```

The perl one liner I am using:

```
perl -Mbignum -ne 'BEGIN{my $sum=0;} s/\r?\n$//; $sum=$sum+$_; print "$_\n"; END{print "TOTAL=$sum"."\n";}' sample.txt
```

The perl one-liner is showing the TOTAL as 40648913273951600.00 and this is INCORRECT.

[image]

EDIT: Following one-liner is showing 40648913273951631.2469 as answer. Now it is really getting weird......

```
perl -Mbignum -e 'my $num1=Math::BigFloat->new("12345678910111213.00"); my $num2=Math::BigFloat->new("14151617181920212.12345"); my $num3=Math::BigFloat->new("23242526272829301.54321"); my $num4=Math::BigFloat->new("32333435363738394.23456"); my $num5=Math::BigFloat->new("-41424344454647489.65432"); my $sum=$num1+$num2+$num3+$num4+$num5; print $sum."\n";'
```

Comment: MS Windows: `perl -pe "$sum+=$_; END{ print \"\nSUM: $sum\n\" }" sum_sample.txt`

Comment: @PolarBear : The TOTAL is not correct. TOTAL is the same number that my perl one liner is producing, which is anyway NOT correct.

Comment: How do you know? Calculator TI-83 Plus produced exactly same number. Perhaps you want formatted output of the result `printf "%.6f\n", $sum`.

Comment: @PolarBear : I edited the question by adding a screenshot. Your suggested perl one liner is showing the output which my perl one-liner is also showing. But that is incorrect. When the contents of sample.txt are pasted to excel, they paste it differently (with rounding off, I guess) and the perl is also adding them up like that, which is distorting the TOTAL

Comment: What is all that commas in the numbers? It does not look right.

Comment: @PolarBear : The comma is to make the number readable in Excel. I removed the commas. But the TOTAL is still incorrect.

Comment: Visit next [webpage](https://miniwebtool.com/sum-calculator/) and try sum numbers there.

Comment: @PolarBear : It shows the TOTAL as 4.0648913274e+16 which is nothing but 40648913274000000 and it is incorrect too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify calculation based on `Math::BigFloat` module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Math::BigFloat;

my $sum = Math::BigFloat->new(0);
$sum->precision(-5);

while( <DATA> ) {
    my $x = Math::BigFloat->new($_);
    $sum->badd($x);
    say $x;
}

say "\nSUM: $sum";

exit 0;

__DATA__
12345678910111213.00
14151617181920212.12345
23242526272829301.54321
32333435363738394.23456
-41424344454647489.65432
```

Output

```
12345678910111213
14151617181920212.12345
23242526272829301.54321
32333435363738394.23456
-41424344454647489.65432

SUM: 40648913273951631.24690
```

Answer (score 2):

The main job of the `bignum` pragma is to turn literal numbers into `Math::BigInt` objects. Once assigned to a variable, that variable will also be an object, and any arithmetic operations carried out using it will be done using `Math::BigInt` operator overloading.

Since you are reading values from a file, they won't automatically be converted into `Math::BigInt` values. So you need something else to be the object, in this case `$sum`. By initialising to the literal 0 value as you have done, `$sum` becomes an object. Unfortunately you declare `my $sum` within the scope of the `BEGIN` block. Outside of this scope, `$sum` refers to a different package variable, which hasn't been initialised into an object.

So you need to declare the variable outside of the `BEGIN`, or add a literal zero to it to coerce it into an object:

`perl -Mbignum -lne' $sum += 0+$_; END {print $sum}'`

Comment: "add a literal zero to it to coerce it into an object"... nice work around,